# Problem with incompatible types while trying to remove element from custom generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want to make my own representation of ArrayList.

Inside my class `MyList<T>` I'm creating `T[] array= (T[]) new Object[size];`

while trying to remove element I have to make another array to compare elements,

so I made `T[] tmpArr=(T[])array;`

I want to rewrite all the elements except one, which I want to remove and I have errors

as I try `array[i]=tmpArr[i+1]`, or `array= tmpArray`   any casting doesn't work, how can I do this?
errors are inside else if and else

```
public void remove() {
        T[] tmpArray= (T[]) new Object[realSize];
        for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
            tmpArray[i]=(T)array[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<size;++i) {
            if (i == current - 1) {

            } else if (i > current - 1) {
                array[i] =tmpArray[i + 1];
            } else {
                array[i] = (T) tmpArray[i];
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The question needs more details. Please consider creating a [mcve]. If it is any help, you can look at [standard library's ArrayList source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) and see how it deals with removal.

Comment: basically I am creating two arrays T[] arr=(T[]) new Object[size], I cannot do stuff like arr[i]=tmpArr[i+1] or arr=tmpArr

Comment: Try to avoid adding details and explanations in comments. It will make things harder for those who want to answer your question. Instead, edit your question and add code/details/explanations as necessary.

Comment: "I have to make another array to compare elements, so I made `T[] tmpArr=(T[])array;`" that doesn't create another array (as an separate object occupying different memory location) but only another *variable* which will hold same reference as `array`. Also your examples should compile fine, unless you are executing them in generic method which defines its own *separate* <T> type which has nothing to do with `<T>` specified at `MyList<T>`.

Comment: Anyway to get proper answer we need to see proper [mcve] (code which we could copy-paste into our computers and *without any modification* reproduce problem you are having).

Comment: Okay, just changed so it doesn't hold same reference and pasted my code

Comment: @mwolm0 While this could help, it is still not [mcve]. I  strongly recommend reading that link. It is very short and can be immensely useful; following it could even help you solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Few questions about your code: 1) what is `size` and `realSize` and what is the relationship between them? 2) why do you have an if statement with an empty body? 3) what is `current`'s role?

Comment: 1) size<=realSize    2) continue; can be inside it   3) its an index +1 on element, which I want  to remove, lets say it's inside an argument

Comment: but it's whatever, I mean the problem is incompatible types, but arrays are the same so I dont get it

Answer (score 0):

This can't work because `new Object[int]` doesn't create a `T[]`, so it can not be casted to one. So what can you do instead? Just have an `Object[]` instead of an `T[]`.

```
public class ArrayList<T>
    private Object[] array = new Object[0];

    public void remove() {
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - 1);
    }

    // Ensures only T objects are place inside Object[] array.
    public void add(T object) {
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
        array[array.length - 1] = object;
    }

    // Actually save, because only T objects can be place inside Object[] array
    public T get(int index) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T obj = (T) array[index];
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Don't just copy this. It's just an example which creates a new array every time the size changes (By adding or removing) which is very inefficent.